# How to track who clicks "Show More" when reading chatter posts

Tags: chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed-tracking

In Chatter if a post or comment is long enough, there is a "Show More" option at the bottom of the post or comment. Is there a way to see how many people have clicked "Show More" for a given post or comment.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks